# A few more steps and he fell to the floor in agony

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

What function does the boldfaced "and" serve in the following passage from a local textbook? I'm asking about its meaning. I'm aware that "and" can connect two phrases and indicate the second as the consequence of the former, as in "One more step and you'll be killed." But apparently, the "and" has a different meaning in the following.

> Derek knew immediately that he was in trouble. The funny pop had been his hamstring tearing. A few more steps **and** he fell to the floor in agony. In severe pain, Derek could only hold his head in his hands as he saw the other competitors sprint to the finish. Four years of hard work and waiting, **and** it was all over in the most distressful way possible.

Comment: The first **and** means that the fall happened after the few steps, the second that his disappointment at being out of the race was the unfortunate end of all his hard work.